# Why are no application folders being created in home folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, lynx

For example, when I do something like...

`sudo apt-get install vim`

No .vim folder is created in the home folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they need not to be created.

Files and folders like `.vim` which begin with a dot are, by convention, hidden from user if a special option is not specified: you need to launch `ls -a` or set the "View hidden files" option in your file manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> also works). This convention is only meaningful when applied to user's home directory and its descendants, and is mainly used for storing user-specific configuration (KDE stores its settings in `~/.config`, GNOME uses that too, apart with `~/.gconf` and several others). They are often created automatically when application is run or its settings are changed, but they are not required to.

When you install an application through APT with tools like `apt-get` or `aptitude`, it spreads package-related files over the entire filesystem (check a [typical file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/coreutils/filelist) for a package). It installs executables in `/usr/bin`, libraries in `/usr/lib`, documentation into `/usr/doc` together with `/usr/man`, and so on. All of these directories are not user-specific: they have nothing to do with your home directory. APT does not ever know about it. Dotfiles (and folders) are *only used by application, not a package manager*.

Imagine a big mainframe with a thousand of user. When a new package is installed, you wouldn't want to update all of users' home directories: this creates a mess in them, this may interfere with their existing configuration, and finally, that wastes disk space!

If you just want to customize your `vim` configuration, create the `.vim` directory by executing `mkdir ~/.vim`.

Comment: Also, a few programs are helpful enough to dump their current config on first run if their `~/.something` doesn't exist. Makes the quest for finding out what exactly you have to edit in order to change settings much easier.